# Evaluate $\int_{x=0}^{2 \pi}\frac{dx}{(1+a \cos{x})^{b^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate:
>   $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{dx}{(l^2+r^2+2 l r \cos{x})^{b^2}}$$
>   where $b^2$ is a real number, $r>0$, and $l \geq 0$.

I can just simplify it to 
$$c\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{dx}{(1+a \cos{x})^{b^2}}$$
where $a>0$.

Any ideas? simplifications? results?

Comment: Do you have access to the residue theorem?

Comment: @Nitin Thanks. That's a good point. I am reading it on Wiki and I know it will take a while for me to understand and use it. Can you help how I can apply that to this problem?

Comment: is $b^2$ integer? is $a>-1$?

Comment: @tired $b^2$ is not integer, it is a real number, and $a>0$.

Comment: bad news..the best you can expect (in gerneral) is some incredibly ugly hypergeometric function

Comment: btw. the $c$ in front of your second integral is completly useless. furthermore i would rename $b^2=\beta \in \mathbb{R}_+$

Comment: Conjecture:
$$I(a,b)/c= \pi \left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)^{-b^2} { _2F_1}\left(\frac12,b^2,1,\frac{2a}{a-1}\right)$$
as long as the integral converges ($|a|<1$)

Comment: @tired, I think that could be proved using the integral representation of the hypergeometric function. But we must convert the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ and apply the substitution $t =\cos (x)$

Comment: @Su20200 i used mathematica

Comment: @tired So, you are sure about the answer?

Comment: Can you explain what is the small "2" behind the F_1 function?

Comment: @Su20200, this is the symbol used for the Gauss Hypergeomtric function. The generalized form is the following ${}_pF_q$$

Comment: @tired $\sin(2\pi/2)=\sin(0/2)=0$. The mapping $t = \sin(x/2)$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: @tired, the function is not symmetric around $\pi$. You 'll have to solve two integrals separately.

Comment: @tired, Nah too lazy to do it. Maybe this will involve some hypergeometric transformation to combine the two integrals.

Comment: For natural values of $b^2,$ evaluate $I(y)=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{y+\cos x},~$ and then differentiate both sides with regard to ***y*,** $~b^2-1$ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to calculate the integral (set $x\rightarrow 2\pi-x$)

$$
I(a,\beta)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1+a \cos(x))^{\beta}}=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{(1+a \cos(x))^{\beta}}=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{(1+a-2a \sin^2(x/2))^{\beta}}
$$

where $|a|<1$ and $\beta\in \mathbb{R}_+$. 
Let us start with a subsitution $y=\sin(x/2)$. This yields

$$
I(a,\beta)=\frac{4}{(1+a)^\beta}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{2a}{1+a} y^2)^{\beta}}
$$

setting $y=t^{1/2}$ we get

$$
I(a,b)=\frac{2}{(1+a)^\beta}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{2a}{1+a} t)^{\beta}}
$$...

which equals by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Integral_formulas) (we use $B(1/2,1)=\Gamma(1/2)^2/\Gamma(1)=\pi$ in the second step)

> $$
> I(a,\beta)=\frac{2}{(1+a)^\beta}B(1/2,1){_2F_1}\left(\beta,\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{2a}{1+a}\right)=\\\frac{2\pi}{(1+a)^\beta}{_2F_1}\left(\beta,\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{2a}{1+a}\right) \quad 
> $$

This reproduces Mathematicas result from the comments by the means of [Pfaff's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Fractional_linear_transformations) 
Set:
$\frac{2a}{1+a}\rightarrow\frac{2a}{a-1}$ and use that $1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ :-)

--

edit: To make the last step more clear:

Due to Pfaff it holds that

$$
_2F_1(a,b;c,z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^b}{_2F_1}\left(b,c-a;c,\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
$$

now we set $z=\frac{2a}{a-1}$,$a=\frac{1}{2}$, $b=\beta$ and $c=1$. We find

$$
\frac{1}{(1-a)^{\beta}}{_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\beta;1,\frac{2a}{a-1}\right)=\frac{1}{(1+a)^{\beta}}{_2F_1}\left(\beta,\frac{1}{2};1,\frac{2a}{a+1}\right)
$$

which also means that

> $$
> I(a,\beta)=\frac{2\pi}{(1-a)^{\beta}}{_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\beta;1,\frac{2a}{a-1}\right)
> $$

which is exactly Mathematicas claim

Comment: +1 maybe you can write some special cases exploiting known values of the Hypergeometric function.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai i'm very bad with hypergeometrics..the case $\beta=1/4$ seems to reduce to an ellipitic integral which i am too stupid to show

Comment: $$I(-1,\beta)=\frac{2\pi}{2^{\beta}}{_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\beta;1,1\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{\beta -1}}\frac{ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} - \beta\right)}{\Gamma(1 - \beta)}$$